# How to ignore lines starting with tilde symbol"~" while parsing?

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, csv, text-files

for all the sub classes that starts with tilde symbol ~ I want to ignore the whole lines

```
 ~ public void visitMethod(org.apache.bcel.classfile.Method arg0): 4
```

i want to ignore all lines that start with  "~"

this is the text file i am parsing

```
gr.spinellis.ckjm.ClassVisitor 13 2 0 14 74 34 2 14 9 0.6042 431 0.8750 1 0.7273 0.2404 0 0 31.5385
 ~ public void visitMethod(org.apache.bcel.classfile.Method arg0): 4
 ~ public void registerCoupling(String arg0): 4
 ~ public void end(): 5
 ~ public void <init>(org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass arg0, gr.spinellis.ckjm.ClassMetricsContainer arg1): 1
 ~ public gr.spinellis.ckjm.ClassMetrics getMetrics(): 1
 ~ private void incRFC(String arg0, String arg1, org.apache.bcel.generic.Type[] arg2): 1
 ~ public void start(): 1
 ~ void registerMethodInvocation(String arg0, String arg1, org.apache.bcel.generic.Type[] arg2): 1
 ~ public void visitField(org.apache.bcel.classfile.Field arg0): 1
 ~ public void visitJavaClass(org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass arg0): 5
 ~ void registerFieldAccess(String arg0, String arg1): 2
 ~ static String className(org.apache.bcel.generic.Type arg0): 3
 ~ public void registerCoupling(org.apache.bcel.generic.Type arg0): 1

gr.spinellis.ckjm.ClassMetricsContainer 3 1 0 4 18 0 2 3 2 0.0000 66 1.0000 0 0.0000 0.5556 0 0 20.6667
 ~ void <init>(): 1
 ~ public gr.spinellis.ckjm.ClassMetrics getMetrics(String arg0): 2
 ~ public void printMetrics(gr.spinellis.ckjm.CkjmOutputHandler arg0): 3

gr.spinellis.ckjm.MetricsFilter 7 1 0 6 30 11 2 6 5 0.6667 218 1.0000 0 0.0000 0.2000 0 0 29.8571
 ~ public static boolean isJdkIncluded(): 1
 ~ static void processClass(gr.spinellis.ckjm.ClassMetricsContainer arg0, String arg1): 3
 ~ public static void runMetrics(String[] arg0, gr.spinellis.ckjm.CkjmOutputHandler arg1): 2
 ~ public static boolean includeAll(): 2
 ~ static void <clinit>(): 1
 ~ public static void main(String[] arg0): 7
 ~ public void <init>(): 1

gr.spinellis.ckjm.PrintPlainResults 2 1 0 3 8 0 1 2 2 0.0000 24 1.0000 0 0.0000 0.6250 0 0 10.5000
 ~ public void handleClass(String arg0, gr.spinellis.ckjm.ClassMetrics arg1): 1
 ~ public void <init>(java.io.PrintStream arg0): 1

gr.spinellis.ckjm.MethodVisitor 11 2 0 21 40 0 1 21 8 0.5500 209 1.0000 1 0.9474 0.1736 0 0 17.6364
 ~ public void visitINSTANCEOF(org.apache.bcel.generic.INSTANCEOF arg0): 1
 ~ public void visitLocalVariableInstruction(org.apache.bcel.generic.LocalVariableInstruction arg0): 2
 ~ public void visitCHECKCAST(org.apache.bcel.generic.CHECKCAST arg0): 1
 ~ private boolean visitInstruction(org.apache.bcel.generic.Instruction arg0): 4
 ~ public void visitInvokeInstruction(org.apache.bcel.generic.InvokeInstruction arg0): 2
 ~ public void visitReturnInstruction(org.apache.bcel.generic.ReturnInstruction arg0): 1
 ~ public void visitArrayInstruction(org.apache.bcel.generic.ArrayInstruction arg0): 1
 ~ public void visitFieldInstruction(org.apache.bcel.generic.FieldInstruction arg0): 1
 ~ void <init>(org.apache.bcel.generic.MethodGen arg0, gr.spinellis.ckjm.ClassVisitor arg1): 1
 ~ public void start(): 5
 ~ private void updateExceptionHandlers(): 3

gr.spinellis.ckjm.CkjmOutputHandler 1 1 0 4 1 0 3 1 1 2.0000 1 0.0000 0 0.0000 1.0000 0 0 0.0000
 ~ public abstract void handleClass(String, 

gr.spinellis.ckjm.ClassMetrics): 1
```

This my full code

```
          package javaapplication59;


        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
        import java.nio.file.Files;
        import java.nio.file.Path;
        import java.nio.file.Paths;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;

        import javafx.application.Application;
        import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
        import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
        import javafx.beans.Observable;
        import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
        import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
        import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
        import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
        import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
        import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
        import javafx.event.Event;
        import javafx.event.EventHandler;
        import javafx.geometry.Pos;
        import javafx.scene.Group;
        import javafx.scene.Scene;
        import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
        import javafx.scene.control.Button;
        import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
        import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
        import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
        import javafx.scene.control.TableView.TableViewSelectionModel;
        import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
        import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
        import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
        import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
        import javafx.scene.text.Text;
        import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class Javajavaapplication59Table extends Application {

    public TableView<Metrics> tableView = new TableView<Metrics>();
    private ObservableList<Metrics> dataList = FXCollections
                    .observableArrayList(


                    );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    primaryStage.setTitle("JAVA JAVA JAVA m");
    VBox root = new VBox();



    TableColumn name = new TableColumn("name");
    name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, String>("name"));

    TableColumn WMCCol = new TableColumn("WMC");
    WMCCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>("WMC"));

    TableColumn DITCol = new TableColumn("DIT");
    DITCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>("DIT"));

    TableColumn NOCCol = new TableColumn("NOC");
    NOCCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>("NOC"));
    TableColumn CBOCol = new TableColumn("CBO");
    CBOCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>("CBO"));
    TableColumn RFCCol = new TableColumn("RFC");
    RFCCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>("RFC"));
    TableColumn LCOMCol = new TableColumn("LCOM");
    LCOMCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(  "LCOM"));
    TableColumn ceCol = new TableColumn("Ca");
    ceCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>("ce"));
    TableColumn NPMCol = new TableColumn("NPM");
    NPMCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>("NPM"));


    // CaCol,LCOM3Col,LOCCol,DAMCol,MOACol,MFACol,CAMCol,ICCol,CBMCCol,AMCCol,CCCol,SUB_NAMECol
    TableColumn CaCol = new TableColumn("Ca");
    CaCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>("Ca"));

    TableColumn LCOM3Col = new TableColumn("LCOM3");
    LCOM3Col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>("LCOM3"));

    TableColumn LOCCol = new TableColumn("LOC");
    LOCCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>("LOC"));

    TableColumn DAMCol = new TableColumn("DAM");
    DAMCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(   "DAM"));

    TableColumn MOACol = new TableColumn("MOA");
    MOACol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>("MOA"));

    TableColumn MFACol = new TableColumn("MFA");
    MFACol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>("MFA"));

    TableColumn CAMCol = new TableColumn("CAM");
    CAMCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>("CAM"));

    TableColumn ICCol = new TableColumn("IC");
    ICCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>("IC"));

    TableColumn CBMCCol = new TableColumn("CBM");
    CBMCCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>("CBM"));

    TableColumn AMCCol = new TableColumn("AMC");
    AMCCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(   "AMC"));



    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();

    List<Metrics> metric = readMetricFromCSV("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\101.txt");
    // let's print all the metric read from CSV file
    for (Metrics m : metric) {
            System.out.println(m);

    }

    tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(metric));
    tableView.getColumns().addAll(name, WMCCol, DITCol, NOCCol, CBOCol,
                    RFCCol, LCOMCol, ceCol, NPMCol,CaCol,LCOM3Col,LOCCol,DAMCol,MOACol,MFACol,CAMCol,ICCol,CBMCCol,AMCCol);

    VBox vBox = new VBox();

    vBox.setSpacing(10);


    HBox boxc = new HBox();
    vBox.prefWidthProperty().bind(root.prefWidthProperty());
    boxc.setManaged(true);
    boxc.getChildren().addAll( tableView);
    vBox.getChildren().add(boxc);

    HBox hbox = new HBox();



    root.getChildren().add(vBox);
    root.getChildren().add(hbox);

    }

    public List<Metrics> readMetricFromCSV(String fileName) {

    List<Metrics> metricsss = new ArrayList<>();

    Path pathToFile = Paths.get(fileName);
    // create an instance of BufferedReader
    // using try with resource, Java 7 feature to close resources
    try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile,
    StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)) {
    // read the first line from the text file
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null && !line.isEmpty()) { // loop until all lines

         if (line.contains("~ ")) {
  continue;
}
                                                    // are read
    String[] attributes = line.split(" "); // the file, using a  comma as the  delimiter first  18 values

    Metrics valueOfMetric = createMetric(attributes);          
    metricsss.add(valueOfMetric); // adding metric into ArrayList
    br.readLine();
    line = br.readLine();
        }

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    return metricsss;
    }

        private Metrics createMetric(String[] metadata) {
    String name = metadata[0];
    int WMC = Integer.parseInt(metadata[1]);
    int DIT = Integer.parseInt(metadata[2]);
    int NOC = Integer.parseInt(metadata[3]);
    int CBO = Integer.parseInt(metadata[4]);
    int RFC = Integer.parseInt(metadata[5]);
    int LCOM = Integer.parseInt(metadata[6]);
    int Ce   = Integer.parseInt(metadata[7]);
    int NPM = Integer.parseInt(metadata[8]);

    int Ca =Integer.parseInt(metadata[9]);
    Double LCOM3 =Double.parseDouble(metadata[10]);
    int LOC =Integer.parseInt(metadata[11]);
    Double DAM =Double.parseDouble(metadata[12]);
    int MOA =Integer.parseInt(metadata[13]);
    Double MFA  =Double.parseDouble(metadata[14]);
    Double CAM =Double.parseDouble(metadata[15]);
    int IC =Integer.parseInt(metadata[16]);
    int CBM  =Integer.parseInt(metadata[17]); 
    Double AMC =Double.parseDouble(metadata[18]);


                return new Metrics(  name, WMC, DIT, NOC, CBO, RFC, LCOM,  Ce,  NPM,   Ca,
                     LCOM3, LOC, DAM, MOA, MFA, CAM, IC, CBM , AMC ) ;
        }





    public class Metrics {

    private String name;
    private int WMC;
    private int DIT;
    private int NOC;
    private int CBO;
    private int RFC;
    private int LCOM;
    private int Ce;
    private int NPM;
    private int Ca;
    private Double LCOM3;
    private int LOC;
    private Double DAM;
    private int MOA;
    private Double MFA;
    private Double CAM;
    private int IC;
    private int CBM ;
    private Double AMC;
    private int CC;
    private String SUB_NAME;

    public Metrics( String name,int WMC,int DIT,int NOC,int CBO,int RFC,int LCOM, int Ce, int NPM,  int Ca,
                    Double LCOM3,int LOC,Double DAM,int MOA,Double MFA,Double CAM,int IC,int CBM ,Double AMC ) {

        this.name = name;
        this.WMC = WMC;
        this.DIT = DIT;
        this.NOC = NOC;
        this.CBO = CBO;
        this.RFC = RFC;
        this.LCOM = LCOM;
        this.Ce = Ce;
        this.NPM = NPM;
        this. Ca =Ca;
        this. LCOM3 =LCOM3;
        this. LOC =LOC;
        this. DAM =DAM;
        this. MOA =MOA;
        this. MFA =MFA;
        this. CAM =CAM;
        this. IC =IC;
        this.CBM  =CBM;
        this. AMC =AMC;

    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getWMC() {
        return WMC;
    }

    public void setWMC(int WMC) {
        this.WMC = WMC;
    }

    public int getDIT() {
        return DIT;
    }

    public void setDIT(int DIT) {
        this.DIT = DIT;
    }

    public int getNOC() {
        return NOC;
    }

    public void setNOC(int NOC) {
        this.NOC = NOC;
    }

    public int getCBO() {
        return CBO;
    }

    public void setCBO(int CBO) {
        this.CBO = CBO;
    }

    public int getRFC() {
        return RFC;
    }

    public void setRFC(int RFC) {
        this.RFC = RFC;
    }

    public int getLCOM() {
        return LCOM;
    }

    public void setLCOM(int LCOM) {
        this.LCOM = LCOM;
    }

    public int getCe() {
        return Ce;
    }

    public void setCe(int ce) {
        Ce = ce;
    }

    public int getNPM() {
        return NPM;
    }

    public void setNPM(int NPM) {
        this.NPM = NPM;
    }

    public int getCa() {
        return Ca;
    }

    public void setCa(int ca) {
        Ca = ca;
    }

    public Double getLCOM3() {
        return LCOM3;
    }

    public void setLCOM3(Double LCOM3) {
        this.LCOM3 = LCOM3;
    }

    public int getLOC() {
        return LOC;
    }

    public void setLOC(int LOC) {
        this.LOC = LOC;
    }

    public Double getDAM() {
        return DAM;
    }

    public void setDAM(Double DAM) {
        this.DAM = DAM;
    }

    public int getMOA() {
        return MOA;
    }

    public void setMOA(int MOA) {
        this.MOA = MOA;
    }

    public Double getMFA() {
        return MFA;
    }

    public void setMFA(Double MFA) {
        this.MFA = MFA;
    }

    public Double getCAM() {
        return CAM;
    }

    public void setCAM(Double CAM) {
        this.CAM = CAM;
    }

    public int getIC() {
        return IC;
    }

    public void setIC(int IC) {
        this.IC = IC;
    }

    public int getCBM() {
        return CBM;
    }

    public void setCBM(int CBM) {
        this.CBM = CBM;
    }

    public Double getAMC() {
        return AMC;
    }

    public void setAMC(Double AMC) {
        this.AMC = AMC;
    }


    }

    }
```

The logical  problem is in this code

```
     public List<Metrics> readMetricFromCSV(String fileName) {

    List<Metrics> metricsss = new ArrayList<>();

    Path pathToFile = Paths.get(fileName);        // create an instance of BufferedReader
                                                  // using try with resource, Java 7 feature to close resources
    try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile,
    StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)) {
    // read the first line from the text file
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null && !line.isEmpty()) { // loop until all lines

         if (line.contains("~ ")) {
            continue;
          }
                                                    // are read
    String[] attributes = line.split(" "); // the file, using a  comma as the  delimiter first  18 values

    Metrics valueOfMetric = createMetric(attributes);          
    metricsss.add(valueOfMetric); // adding metric into ArrayList
    br.readLine();
    line = br.readLine();
        }

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    return metricsss;
    }
```

Comment: *"The logical problem is in this code"* Telling us what the logical problem is, was to hard, right? That's sad.

Answer (score 0):

See I would go the other way with it.

```
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
       if(!line.contains("~")){
             String[] attributes = line.split(" ");
             Metrics valueOfMetric = createMetric(attributes);          
             metricsss.add(valueOfMetric); 
       }
    }
}
```

Often times it's easier/better to use negative lookups instead of positive lookups. By using !Line you essentially avoid the unnecessary code of continue (not saying you cant use it, but there are more areas for code to go wrong). Then at the end of your code you are using

```
br.readline()
line = br.readline()
```

which might not be in itself breaking your code, it is just really really unnecessary.

So this code will read to the end of the file, avoid nulls, and avoid lines with "~".

Comment: You should explain what you did here that solved the problem.

Comment: It seems that he wants to read all the lines that dont involve a "~" ... This not only solves that but it gets rid of quite a bit of the poor coding including the "continue", the br.readline, and the line=br.readline which are all unnecessary.... A short/sweet/concise/(should be)working answer....

Comment: What I meant is - your answer is too short and cryptic. Instead of adding the explanation in a comment, you should expand your answer, explain what the problem was with the old code, and what your new code does. This way, your answer could be useful not just to this person but to others that happen to have a similar question.

Comment: ahhhhh - the ol' teaching aspect of helping... one second : P

Comment: Did you try mine again after the fixed ")"?

Comment: @Nefariiّ   Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Comment: You: *"It seems that he wants to read all the lines that dont involve a "~""* -> OP: *"i want to ignore all lines that start with "~""* ... do you see the contradiction?

Comment: @Tom - The reason that I posted the code to !contain instead of to !startwith is that nothing would lead me to believe that any of the lines that he is analyzing would contain a "~" and not have the "~" be the starting character. There is no reason to make the code more complicated if if doesnt add value.

Answer (score 0):

Use [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) `CsvParser`. It has support for comment characters at the start of a line and can easily handle your input CSV:

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings(); //many options here, check the tutorial

settings.getFormat().setComment('~');     

// creates a CSV parser
CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

// parses all rows in one go.
List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new FileReader(new File("/path/to/file.csv")));
```